# why we use nested using statement in c#?

Tags: c#, using, using-statement

```
using (StreamReader outFile = new StreamReader(outputFile.OpenRead())) 
{    
   StreamReader resFile = new StreamReader(resultFile.OpenRead())    
   {       //Some Codes    }
}
```

Why does the above resFile object not close automatically?

I wrote the resFile object inside the using statement also. Please explain the `using` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't use nested using. There's only one using statement.

An example of nested using:

```
using (...)
{
     using (...)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

The reason why you may want to use nested using is that you have more than one declaration that need to be disposed.

Comment: that means each declaration should have one using statement then only it's disposed of. otherwise, it's not disposed of automatically, even if we declare it inside the using blocks. Is correct?

Comment: The immediate calls to the `Dispose()` method will be done once the using statement is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Find the official explanation for the using statement here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

In your example you are not having a nested using statement as Mark said correctly in his answer. (Though you should have a second using for the resFile Streamreader.

They have to be nested, if you want to use both stream readers in the "// Some Codes" part, as the instances for outFile and resFile are only available inside the curly brackets.

Starting from C#8 there is a new possibility for usings that "avoids" the nesting. See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using

Answer (score 0):

[`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) is syntactic sugar and basically compiles to the following:

Original code:

```
using (var a = b)
{    
  c();
  d();
}
```

Desugared code:

```
{
  var a;
  try {
    a = b;
    c();
    d();
  } finally {
    if (a != null) {
      ((IDisposable)a).Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```